# Error when installing Jboss AS, wildfly & EAP Server Tools in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jboss, wildfly

I have Eclipse 2021-03 installed with Monterey OS. I tried to install Jboss AS / Wildly Server.

I tried to add from servers tab, but it keep getting me error about :

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
> context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
> phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
> action=).
>
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.jboss.tools.common.jdt.debug,3.17.100.v20211005-0922
>
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.jboss.tools.common.jdt.debug.ui,3.17.100.v20211005-0922
>
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.jboss.tools.foundation.checkup,1.6.1000.v20211004-1419
>
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.jboss.tools.foundation.core,1.6.1000.AM1-v20211209-1014
>
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.jboss.tools.foundation.ui,1.6.1000.v20211004-1419
>
> No repository found containing:
> osgi.bundle,org.jboss.tools.usage,2.2.400.v20211118-0919

I also tried to use offline update from jboss site, but no luck.

How can I fix this ?

Comment: In the preferences _Install/Update > Available Software Sites_ add a repository that contains the plugin/bundle `org.jboss.tools.usage` of version 2.2.400.v20211118-0919.

Comment: No luck downloading an offline update site, or no luck using a downloaded one?

Answer (score 1):

Finally i succeeded... but not sure it can help you.
Here're the what i tried.

**option 1. Market place**

1. Help > Eclipse Marketplace... > search 'JBoss Tools' or 'Red Hat CodeReady Studio' you need.
2. this option already failed but after change eclipse version based on [JBoss Tools Archived Downloads](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/archives.html) and try below options, it worked.

**option 2. Install New Software with the link**

1. Find version that your eclipse version support from [JBoss Tools Archived Downloads](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/archives.html)
2. Follow 'Update Site' guide

**option 3.  Install New Software with the zip (offline download)**

1. Find version that your eclipse version support from [JBoss Tools Archived Downloads](https://tools.jboss.org/downloads/archives.html)
2. Follow 'Artifacts' guide

Comment: I tried with offline site, but it didnt work.

Comment: @GerryGry How about the Eclipse Market place

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you disabled "Help → Install new software → Contact all update sites during install to find required software" during installation and try again